# What is my Jquery slide menu code error?

Tags: jquery, slide

Hello Im new to javascript, I cant get my code work, can you help me find whats wrong with my codes? Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/FYt8s/

Comment: You forgot to set the right Javascript library on jsfiddle and used index instead of index(). After fixing that the code still doesn't work but it's a start.

Comment: I did the corrections but still doesnt work :( thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your selected library was not the right one.
I edited your code and I think this is what you had in mind:

http://jsfiddle.net/FYt8s/16/